# How do I code a page to display a video similar to youtube?

Tags: html, video, embed, mp4

I am looking to create a playable video on an html page. I currently have a video file (mp4) and simply want to display it on our companies intranet without involving youtube. It would be awesome if someone could provide a basic html template. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let me answer between the lines for you Mitch. Yes I have searched google and no I haven't found an easy answer. Just a lot of reasons why certain video file extensions work and why some other are preferred.  I figured asking the question in a simple form would help others looking as well. Not only could you not answer my incredibly easy question (as you infer) but you also had to waste peoples time my commenting in a negatively sarcastic tone that really doesn't help anyone.  Then on top of that, you mark my question as a negative. Thanks Mitch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at here:

http://jsfiddle.net/dsbonev/cCCZ2/

```
<h1>HTML5 local video file player example</h1>
<div id="message"></div>
<input type="file" accept="video/*"/>
<video controls autoplay></video>
```

Hope it helps.